# NoSuchMethodError with inherited HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, inheritance, hashmap

I tried to find something similar to my problem, but was not successful.
My IDE and the compiler is happy about the implementation, but at runtime I get a "`NoSuchMethodError`"-exception thrown.
Let's assume, I have 3 classes.

Class A

```
public final class MyEnumMap<V> extends HashMap<Integer, V> {
...
}
```

Class B

```
public class B {
...

    private static transient MyEnumMap<Type> enumeration = new MyEnumMap<Type>();

    /**
     * @return enumeration
     */
    public static final Map<Integer, Type> getEnumeration () { 
        return enumeration;
    }

...
}
```

Class C

```
public class C {
...

 public List<Long> resolveSomething(Long Id) throws PCEException {
     Map<Integer, Type> myTypes = B.getEnumeration();
 }

...
}
```

At runtime the following error is thrown:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com/my/package/path/B.getEnumeration()Ljava/util/HashMap;

I can see that the calling method in class C expects the result to be a `HashMap` (`Ljava/util/HashMap`), but as far as I am concerned, the class I wrote inherits from `HashMap` (see the first class "`MyEnumMap`", which inherits from `HashMap`). So - where is the issue here? Is it because I am trying to do the "`B.getEnumeration`" and try to put it in a type safe `<Integer, Type> Map`, whilst "`MyEnumMap`" actually just holds Values (see `MyEnumMap<V>`)?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: `Type` is actually another own class I wrote.

Comment: the stacktrace suggest B is instance of HashMap not B so the getEnumeration() method is not there...

Comment: it is like you didn't not recompile properly

Comment: But why should I have to do this? My own created `MyEnumMap` inherits from `HashMap` - so should it even bother about the fact that it now receives a child of the `HashMap` class instead of the `HashMap` itself?

EDIT: the method `getEnumeration()` is present - checked it.

Comment: So I already found out that it has something to do with the compilation as it seems (thanks @NicolasFilotto). If I write some test-classes to test the described scenario, everything works just fine. Still I am struggling with what went wrong here. Is there anyone who knows what happens here at compilation time and why it could've gone wrong?

Comment: What's your IDE? Are those classes in the same project? Are those classes both somewhere under src folder (maybe not directly)? Can you please take a screenshot of your project file tree and post it?

Comment: The classes are in two different JARs and actually I found the issue:
the JARs were deployed separately and manually in the container. JAR1 with the calling method was compiled when the class in JAR2 with the called method still returned a HashMap. The class was then changed to return a Map instead of a HashMap and this is why it crashed.
Hence: an issue with the process (the good man did not follow the regular deployment process), rather than with the coding.